# Autoplay audio on nativescript webview

Tags: nativescript, audio-streaming

I've successfully embed an audio streaming into nativescript webview with code below.

```
getViewById(page,"myWebView").src = "http://live.indostreamserver.com:8054/stream/7/";
```

The question is how and could it be autoplayed once it loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing the native widgets and use the native approach.

For example something like this on Android

XML

```
<WebView loaded="onWebViewLoaded" src="http://live.indostreamserver.com:8054/stream/7/" />
```

TypeScript

```
export function onWebViewLoaded(args) {
    let webView = <WebView>args.object;

    if (isAndroid) {
        setTimeout(() => {
           let androidWebView = webView.nativeView; // android.webkit.WebView
           androidWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: As I used native javascript, I change the code into this. Thanks for your help.

function onWebViewLoaded(webargs){
 const webview = webargs.object;
 const androidWebView = webview.nativeView;
 androidWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
}